# Silverlight 3 custom control: only 'int' as numeric type for a property? [e.g. long or int64 seems to break]

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I'm trying to add a new property to a Silverlight 3 custom control of mine. An int property works perfectly, but if I change it to a long or an int64, I've got a xaml parser exception on runtime.

Do you know if it's a known restriction in SL3?

C# side, new control:

```
public class myExtTextBox : TextBox
{
    public int MaxNumericValue { get; set; }
    //public long MaxLongNumericValue { get; set; }  => This breaks the parser
}
```

XAML side:

```
<myExtTextBox x:Name="foobar"  MaxNumericValue="12" /> <!-- OK -->

<myExtTextBox x:Name="foobar"  MaxLongNumericValue="12" /> <!-- Breaks parser -->
```

Comment: Could you showUp ur XAML , to understand your problem better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is odd in my view that Xaml can't parse all types that implement `IConvertible`.  (I'd love to know the reason if any of you MS lurkers care to edify?)

Here is an implementation that may help:-

```
public class ConvertibleTypeConverter<T> : TypeConverter where T: IConvertible
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType.GetInterface("IConvertible", false) != null;
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        return destinationType.GetInterface("IConvertible", false) != null;
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        return ((IConvertible)value).ToType(typeof(T), culture);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        return ((IConvertible)value).ToType(destinationType, culture);
    }
}
```

Now on the `MaxLongNumericValue` property you use an attribute like this:-

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ConvertibleTypeConverter<long>))]
public long MaxLongNumericValue { get; set; }
```

Now when the Xaml parser gets to this property it will defer to the specified `TypeConverter`.